# Go package installation failing for unknown certificate authority

Tags: go, mercurial, debian

I'm attempting to install a Go module from bitbucket as follows:

```
go get bitbucket.org/kardianos/osext
```

But I receive the following error:

> package bitbucket.org/kardianos/osext: Get https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/kardianos/osext: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Google lead me to the instructions at  [this post](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Debian.2FUbuntu.2FGentoo.2FArch_Linux), which I have followed by editing `/etc/mercurial/hgrc` to contain:

```
[web]
cacerts = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

as instructed for my OS (Debian), however I still receive the same error.

what else can I do?

Comment: What version of Go are you using? This was fixed before: https://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=c70d7dfc

Comment: @VonC: Nice... it looks like I'm still using 1.0.2 (the version provided with Debian wheezy). I'll try upgrading and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it looks like I'm still using 1.0.2 (the version provided with Debian wheezy)

Considering that this looks like a [Go 1.0 bug](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=c70d7dfc), the first thing to check is to upgrade Go to 1.3+.

> net/http: use tls host instead of proxy, when checking against a certificate

That could solve the certificate issue.
[Golang Debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=golang) mentions 1.3.2 (but for Debian Jessie, not wheezy)

You can follow "[How to install Golang 1.1(+) in Debian from repository](http://eugenioz.blogspot.fr/2013/07/how-to-install-golang-11-in-debian-from.html) " for more.
(Done after "[How can I run Debian stable but install some packages from testing?](https://serverfault.com/a/382101/783)")